# Pyomo (PySP) is changing "\" into " /"

Tags: python, pyomo

When I use the `runef` command `(PySP)` in Anaconda Prompt (Windows operating system)

```
(base) D:\Downloads\Documents\models_Opt_estocastica> runef --solve --solver=gurobi
```

I'm getting the error:

```
"runef: IO ERROR:
path does not exist: D:/Downloads/Documents/models_Opt_estocastica/ReferenceModel.py
```

The problem is that `Pyomo` is changing the "\" symbol to the "/" symbol so it doesn't recognize the path I'm giving. Do you have any idea how I can fix this problem?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Why would it not recognize the path because it has forward slashes? Windows is perfectly fine with forward slashes. Most likely the problem is something else; ask about solving that problem rather than assuming you already know what the solution is and just need to implement it.

Comment: Can you run `dir` in `D:\Downloads\Documents\models_Opt_estocastica>` and paste the results?